# Where does Spring boot application scan the annotations , create beans and inject them

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I wanted to understand as to how spring boot application scan the annotations, create the beans and inject them, so I create a simple spring boot CRUD application.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FullE2eCrudAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FullE2eCrudAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I run it in debug mode, and I possibly "Stepped-into" all the methods calls right from `SpringApplication.run()`. Admittedly, the code is quite complex to "spot" that piece which I am looking for.

I debugged ample times, but not able to find those spots where it does:

1. Scan all the annotations (like: @Autowire, @Component, @Service etc.)
2. Create those Beans
3. Inject those beans where-ever they are used (may be by Byte code manipulation, eg. using ASM)

Is my understanding correct that these steps are actually performed? Any pointers in locating those spots where I see these things happing in real.

Answer (score 1):

Core initialization of @Bean in spring-boot is done while creation of `ApplicationContext` into class `org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication` ("run" method) and more specifically into `org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext` into method refresh:

spring-boot 3.2.0:

run method:

```java
    public ConfigurableApplicationContext run(String... args) {
        Startup startup = Startup.create();
        if (this.registerShutdownHook) {
            SpringApplication.shutdownHook.enableShutdownHookAddition();
        }
        DefaultBootstrapContext bootstrapContext = createBootstrapContext();
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = null;
        configureHeadlessProperty();
        SpringApplicationRunListeners listeners = getRunListeners(args);
        listeners.starting(bootstrapContext, this.mainApplicationClass);
        try {
            ApplicationArguments applicationArguments = new DefaultApplicationArguments(args);
            ConfigurableEnvironment environment = prepareEnvironment(listeners, bootstrapContext, applicationArguments);
            Banner printedBanner = printBanner(environment);
            context = createApplicationContext();
            context.setApplicationStartup(this.applicationStartup);
            prepareContext(bootstrapContext, context, environment, listeners, applicationArguments, printedBanner);
            refreshContext(context);
            afterRefresh(context, applicationArguments);
            startup.started();
            if (this.logStartupInfo) {
                new StartupInfoLogger(this.mainApplicationClass).logStarted(getApplicationLog(), startup);
            }
            listeners.started(context, startup.timeTakenToStarted());
            callRunners(context, applicationArguments);
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            if (ex instanceof AbandonedRunException) {
                throw ex;
            }
            handleRunFailure(context, ex, listeners);
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        try {
            if (context.isRunning()) {
                listeners.ready(context, startup.ready());
            }
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            if (ex instanceof AbandonedRunException) {
                throw ex;
            }
            handleRunFailure(context, ex, null);
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return context;
    }
```

refresh method:

```java
    public void refresh() throws BeansException, IllegalStateException {
        synchronized (this.startupShutdownMonitor) {
            StartupStep contextRefresh = this.applicationStartup.start("spring.context.refresh");

            // Prepare this context for refreshing.
            prepareRefresh();

            // Tell the subclass to refresh the internal bean factory.
            ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = obtainFreshBeanFactory();

            // Prepare the bean factory for use in this context.
            prepareBeanFactory(beanFactory);

            try {
                // Allows post-processing of the bean factory in context subclasses.
                postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);

                StartupStep beanPostProcess = this.applicationStartup.start("spring.context.beans.post-process");
                // Invoke factory processors registered as beans in the context.
                invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(beanFactory);

                // Register bean processors that intercept bean creation.
                registerBeanPostProcessors(beanFactory);
                beanPostProcess.end();

                // Initialize message source for this context.
                initMessageSource();

                // Initialize event multicaster for this context.
                initApplicationEventMulticaster();

                // Initialize other special beans in specific context subclasses.
                onRefresh();

                // Check for listener beans and register them.
                registerListeners();

                // Instantiate all remaining (non-lazy-init) singletons.
                finishBeanFactoryInitialization(beanFactory);

                // Last step: publish corresponding event.
                finishRefresh();
            }

            catch (RuntimeException | Error ex ) {
                if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
                    logger.warn("Exception encountered during context initialization - " +
                            "cancelling refresh attempt: " + ex);
                }
                // Destroy already created singletons to avoid dangling resources.
                destroyBeans();

                // Reset 'active' flag.
                cancelRefresh(ex);

                // Propagate exception to caller.
                throw ex;
            }

            finally {
                contextRefresh.end();
            }
        }
    }
```